# Dynamic Programming - Given num K, how many ways to get from (0,0) to (x,y)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, coordinates, dynamic-programming, random-walk

A robot is moving in the (x~y) coordinate system according to a plan that was attached to him prior to his start.
The robot always starts at (0, 0) and only understands 4 commands -
WEST - (x-1, y)
SUD - (x, y-1)
OST - (x+1, y)
NORD - (x, y+1)
Every command lets the robot move one unit in the chosen direction.
The robot's attached plan is made of a sequence of these commands.

Given a random coordinate for (x, y) and a natural number K, we want to calculate the number of different plans in the length of K that would bring the robot from (0, 0) to (x, y).

Aside of an explanation, I need an algorithm and the pseudo-code for it
preferrably in C

So far, only thing I could think about is that the main condition would be that K cannot be smaller than abs(x+y), in this case i'd need to return 0 since there are zero sequences of K length that will get me to (x,y), or, more accurately, i'll never be able to get there with K steps.

Comment: Can the coordinates along the path be negative?

Comment: The distance to the goal is the [manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), which is `|x1-x2| + |y1-y2|`. If a move would put the robot at a location where the distance to the goal is greater than the number of remaining moves, then that move is invalid.

Comment: Side note: the parity of `x+y` must be equal to the parity of `K`. If not, no solution.

Comment: Solomon yes.
Damien, i don't need a solution to happen though,  I need to return the amount of different sequences of commands to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming with the following observation: f(x, y, K) = f(x - 1, y, K - 1) + f(x + 1, y, K - 1) + f(x, y - 1, K - 1) + f(x, y + 1, K - 1)